# node.js- How to get the parent of the node whose child has changed and grand child has added?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my json file:

```
{
    "ERyWg81WxrXUb0sjsu9hv9T7K0E3" : {
            "intents" : {
            "intentName" : "",
            "intentValue" : ""
          },
          "messages" : {
            "-KViVgc7ZG051eMXP0-5" : {
              "name" : "Ed",
              "text" : "Hello, I'm Ed, your personal assistant cum friend",
              "timestamp" : "1476880306"
            }
          }         
    },
    "Y9UNlizDSobddO8cdq7K4ChipYa2" : {
        "intents" : {
            "intentName" : "",
            "intentValue" : ""
          },
          "messages" : {
            "-KViVgc7ZG051eMXP0-5" : {
              "name" : "Ed",
              "text" : "Hello, I'm Ed, your personal assistant cum friend",
              "timestamp" : "1476880306"
            }
          } 
    }
}
```

Here, `ERyWg81WxrXUb0sjsu9hv9T7K0E3` and `Y9UNlizDSobddO8cdq7K4ChipYa2` are user Ids and they have two children namely, `intents` and `messages` who further have their children as shown in the JSON structure above.
Now, when a user sends a message, the message is added to the `messages` child of the user. Also ,it must be noted that other users can also be added or removed from the database.
Therefore, when a message is added, how to know the id of the user whose has messaged. For eg: I should get `ERyWg81WxrXUb0sjsu9hv9T7K0E3` when `ERyWg81WxrXUb0sjsu9hv9T7K0E3` user messages and a message is added to the `messages` subdirectory of `ERyWg81WxrXUb0sjsu9hv9T7K0E3`. I have to do this using firebase node.js sdk on server side.

For reference, my node.js server side code for getting new messages is:

```
var db = firebase.database();
var ref = db.ref("/");
console.log("Listening ...\n");
var text, name, timeStamp;
var newPost = {};
ref.on("child_changed", function(snapshot){
    snapshot.child("messages").forEach(function(itemSnapshot) {
        text = itemSnapshot.child("text").val();
        name = itemSnapshot.child("name").val();
        timeStamp = itemSnapshot.child("timeStamp").val();
  });
```

Comment: ChildChanged events are designed to notify the app when, well... a child has changed. The changed node (parent and children) are sent do the app. Do you need something more?

Comment: @Jay, I need to get the data at the server(node.js Firebase SDk), not on the app. And I am getting the new messages already as of now by using the "child_changed" and "child_added" listeners in a nested function. What I need is to get the name of the user who has sent the message(or in other terms, the id whose child has changed and grandchild is added

Comment: Where do you store the 'name' of the person that made the change or sent the message. Is that the 'name: Ed' key:value in the message in the messages node?

Comment: 'name` is just for displaying in the app. All the work is done using the id of the user. eg: in the above json database their are two users: `ERyWg81WxrXUb0sjsu9hv9T7K0E3` and `Y9UNlizDSobddO8cdq7K4ChipYa2`. For your reference I am adding the node.js code in the question.

Comment: The actual problem is that I don't know which user has messaged although I know what the message is.

Comment: Hmm. You may want to think through how you are working with your data. For example. If you add a new message to a messages node, you would have to know the parent. i.e. If Ed writes another message you would need to write it to Y9UNlizDSobddO8cdq7K4ChipYa2/messages/the new msg node. If you are adding observers to the specific messages node you would also need to know the parent to add the observer in the first place. You may want to attach the observer to the uid itself so you know the parent when an event occurs or include the uid in the node itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no fundamental difference between using the admin (a.k.a. server) SDK and the client SDKs. The event listeners behave exactly the same.

You will not get the information you are looking for from the child event listeners, neither about the parent, nor which descendant triggered the change.

You need to change your database schema and/or your subscription strategy to facilitate your goals. At the very least, you should:

1. Have a single (**not** per-user) node for **all** outgoing messages the server can simply observe. A `child_added` event will mean a message getting sent.
2. Include the sender, recipient information in the message itself.
   You can use security rules to make sure that the client cannot falsify the sender's identity. With some creativity, you can also ensure that a user may only send another messages if he has permission to do do.